# Allow Drupal Organic Group Admins delete and edit access to all group nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, access-control, organic-groups

We have a Drupal site that uses Organic Groups to represent companies. I'm looking for a module that will allow us to give edit and delete access to group admins for all posts that are associated with that group.

Is there a module that exposes this type of relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/og_user_roles

This module lets you attach edit/delete permissions to roles but only in the group context. So build a "group admin" role and set that as the default role for group managers. There is also options for regular group members. The users will only appear to have the role when they're looking at their group or posts within the group. They don't have the role in the traditional sense which can be confusing.

Comment: Oh. . . thanks for explaining that module better than the module page. Have you used it yourself?

Comment: Yes I'm using it on an OG heavy project and it does exactly what you want. It's been a long time since I've tested with it though.